# Proving $f(x)=x^2$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,b]$ for any $b\gt 0$. 

Tags: real-analysis

> Consider the real function $f$ defined on the real line $\mathbb{R}$ by $f(x)=x^2$. If $b$ is a given positive real number, show that the restriction of $f$ to the closed interval $[0,b]$ is uniformly continuous by starting with an $e\gt 0$ and exhibiting a $d\gt 0$ which satisfies the requirement of the definition

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: This is a special case of the fact that a continuous function on a compact set is uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way to prove this fact comes in the form of the following theorem.

> **Theorem.** Let $K \subseteq \mathbb{R}^N$ compact, and $f:K \to \mathbb{R}$ continuous. Then $f$ is uniformly continuous.
>
> **Proof.** Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. By continuity of $f$, for every $x_0 \in K$ choose $\delta(x_0)$ such that if $x \in K$ with $\Vert x-x_0 \Vert < \delta(x_0)$ then $\Vert f(x)- f(x_0) \Vert < \epsilon/2$. The family of open balls $\{B(x,\frac{1}{2}\delta(x)) : x \in K \}$ forms an open cover of $K$. By compactness of $K$ we may choose finitely many $x_1,\ldots, x_n \in K$ such that $\{B(x_i,\frac{1}{2}\delta(x_i)) : 1 \leq i \leq n \}$ still covers $K$. Choose $\delta = \frac{1}{2}\min\{\delta(x_i) : 1 \leq i \leq n \}$. Then for any $x,y \in K$ with $\Vert x - y \Vert< \delta$ there is $i$ with $1\leq i \leq n$ so that $x \in B(x_0,\frac{1}{2}\delta(x_0))$ and $\Vert x_i - y \Vert \leq \Vert x_i - x \Vert + \Vert x-y \Vert < \frac{1}{2}\delta(x_i) + \frac{1}{2}\delta(x_i) \leq \delta(x_i)$. Thus we have $x,y \in B(x_i,\delta(x_i))$ and by the triangle inequality we have $\Vert f(x) -f(y) \Vert \leq \Vert f(x)-f(x_i) \Vert + \Vert f(x_i) - f(y) \Vert < \epsilon/2 + \epsilon/2 = \epsilon. ~~\square$

In the case of this problem, we know that $[0,b]$ is compact for all $b>0$ since it is closed and bounded, and that $x \longmapsto x^2$ is continuous on $[0,b]$. Hence by the previous theorem $x \longmapsto x^2$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,b]$.

Note: if this is a homework problem, this is probably not the solution your professor is looking for, but it is an extremely useful theorem that you might want to know about anyway.

Answer (score 3):

If a continuous function f satisfies the property $|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|\le M|x_1-x_2|$ is said to be Lipschitz with constant $M$, and $f$ must be uniformly continuous as in this case  you will get $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{M}$ all the time which will allow your continuous function to be uniformly continuous. For your function we have $|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|=|(x_1^2-x_2^2)|=|(x_1-x_2)(x_1+x_2)|\le 2b|x_1-x_2|$. I hope you can do now.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: for $|h|\le1$ and $x\in[0,b]$, we have $$|x^2-(x+h)^2|=|-2xh-h^2|=|h| |h+2x|\le |h|\cdot (2b+1).$$

Given $\epsilon>0$, you essentially find the "$d$ that works" for $x=b$. Then this $d$ will work for all $x\in[0,b]$.