# Prove that $f(x)=x^2$ is uniformly continuous in [a,b]

Tags: real-analysis

I'm expanding [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133571/proving-fx-x2-is-uniformly-continuous-on-0-b-for-any-b-gt-0) question, this time supposing that the inverval in which the uniform continuity of the function has to be proved is the more general closed interval $[a,b]$.

I'm asking this because in my book there is a proof of this sort:

For $|x_1-x_2| < \delta$, we have $|f(x_2)-f(x_1)| = |x_2^2-x_1^2| = |x_2-x_1||x_2+x_1| \leq 2|x_2-x_1|(|b|+|a|) \lt 2 \delta (|b| + |a|) = \epsilon $. So $\delta = \epsilon/(|a|+|b|)$.

I just don't understand why $|x_2-x_1||x_2+x_1|$ should be $\leq 2|x_2 - x_1|(|b|+|a|)$.

In fact, if you apply the triagle inequality  to $|x_2-x_1||x_2+x_1|$, that is to $|x_2-x_1||2x_1+(x_2-x_1)|$you have that this is $ \leq |x_2-x_1|(2|x_1|+|x_2-x_1|)$.

But now, since you only know that the distance between $x_1$ and $x_2$ is less than the one between $a$ and $b$, even if you apply the triangle inequality again to write that $|x_2-x_1| \leq |a-b| \leq |a| + |b|$ (thus substituting the $|x_2-x_1|$ in the brackets with $|a| + |b|$, since the one outside is needed as $\delta$), you could never get rid of that $2|x_1|$ remaining, and even if you write it as $2|x_2+(x_1-x_2)|$, applying the triangle inequality again, you will end up forever with either $x_1$ or $x_2$ which don't seem to suggest that the function is uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$.

In an answer to the question I'm expanding, the chosen $\delta$ is $\epsilon/2b$, which seems basically the $\delta$ chosen in my book, given that $a=0$ and $b>0$. The problem is that in this particular case, where both $a$ and $b$ are nonnegative, one could simply write $|x_2-x_1||x_2+x_1| \leq |x_2-x_1|(|x_2|+|x_1|) \leq |x_2-x_1|(|b|+|b|)$, thus choosing $\delta = \epsilon/2|b|$; I, instead, can't get rid of either $|x_1|$ or $|x_2|$, since I can't know wheter these are less than or greater than $ |a|$ and $|b|$, because they can be either positive or negative.

Am I missing something important here? I hope so, since I can't really figure out this problem.

One last additional thing: my book says that $[a,b]$ must be a "fixed finite closed set" and then says "The restriction to bounded intervals is essential as the example of the function $x^2$ shows." However, I don't actually feel such an urgence to specify the precence of bounds in the closed interval $[a,b]$: isn't it just bounded by definition, since it's a closed interval on the real line, whose bounds are therefore $a$ and $b$?

Maybe some clarification on this may help in solving the problem above.
Thanks.

Comment: Isn't $|x_1 + x_2| \le 2||a|+|b||$ obvious?

Comment: No, sorry, not so obvious... Can you explain better?

Comment: Regarding your last question, the reason why restriction to bounded intervals is necessary is because $x^2$ is not uniformly continuous over unbounded sets like $\mathbb{R}$ or $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: $|x_1+x_2| \leq |x_1|+|x_2| \leq 2 \max \{|a|,|b|\} \leq 2(|a|+|b|)$.

Comment: @angryavian Yes, I know, but wouldn't just be sufficient to restrict to closed intervals? What is the main difference between "closed" and "bounded" here?

Comment: The OP is asking why not just use $2|b|$ rather than the larger $2(|a|+|b|)$, assuming $b>a>0$.  The form expressed in the book covers all cases, including negative values of $a$ and or $b$,

Comment: @RiccardoDelMonte My previous comment shows that we need to restrict to bounded sets. To see why being closed is needed, we unfortunately need to consider a different example. The function $f(x)=1/x$ is not uniformly continuous on $(0,1]$.

Comment: @angryavian Yes, and in this example, if you take the interval $[0,1]$, this interval is bounded, but $0$ isn't in the domain of $f$, so here it's again not uniformly continuous. Instead, if we take an interval of the type $[a,b]$, with, say, $a,b > 0$, then you have an uniformly continuous function with modulus of continuity $\delta = a^2\epsilon$. But, anyway, what I was actually asking you was wheter this interval $[a,b]$, even in this other example, must be called "bounded", "closed", or "closed and bounded", as my book does. I actually don't get the difference between these terms

Comment: @RiccardoDelMonte: The interval $[a,\infty)$ is closed and unbounded. “Closed” means containing its endpoint(s) (in this case the interval has only one endpoint, namely $a$), while “unbounded” means going out to $\infty$ and/or $-\infty$. The same for $(-\infty,b]$. And $(-\infty,\infty)$ is closed (vacuously, since it has no endpoints) *and* open and unbounded!

Answer (score 2):

$$a \le x_i \le b \Longrightarrow |x_i| \le \max \{ |a|,|b|\} \le |a|+|b|$$
so
$$|x_1|+|x_2| \le 2 (|a|+|b|)$$